# use std::thread::id in map to have thread safe

Tags: c++, multithreading

The idea is to have instance for each thread, so I created new instance for every new `thread::id` like that :

```
struct doSomething{
    void test(int toto) {}
};

void test(int toto)
{
    static std::map<std::thread::id, doSomething *> maps;

    std::map<std::thread::id, doSomething *>::iterator it = maps.find(std::this_thread::get_id());
    if (it == maps.end())
    {
        // mutex.lock() ?
        maps[std::this_thread::get_id()] = new doSomething();
        it = maps.find(std::this_thread::get_id());
        // mutex.unlock() ?
    }
    it->second->test(toto);
}
```

Is it a good idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having a mutex lock after you've accessed the map would not be enough. You can't go anywhere near the map without a mutex because another thread might take the mutex to modify the map while you are reading from it.

```
{
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(my_mutex);
    std::map<std::thread::id, doSomething *>::iterator it = maps.find(std::this_thread::get_id());
    if (it != maps.end())
        return *it;
    auto ptr = std::make_unique<doSomething>();
    maps[std::this_thread::get_id()] = ptr.get();
    return ptr.release();
}
```

But unless you have some special/unique use case, this is an already-solved problem through [thread-local storage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread-local_storage), and since you have C++11 you have the [`thread_local` storage specifier](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration).

Note that I'm using a `mutex` here because `cout` is a shared resource and `yield` just to encourage a little more interleaving of the workflow.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>

static std::mutex cout_mutex;

struct CoutGuard : public std::unique_lock<std::mutex> {
    CoutGuard() : unique_lock(cout_mutex) {}
};

struct doSomething {
    void fn() {
        CoutGuard guard;
        std::cout << std::this_thread::get_id() << " running doSomething "
            << (void*)this << "\n";
    }
};

thread_local std::unique_ptr<doSomething> tls_dsptr; // DoSomethingPoinTeR

void testFn() {
    doSomething* dsp = tls_dsptr.get();
    if (dsp == nullptr) {
        tls_dsptr = std::make_unique<doSomething>();
        dsp = tls_dsptr.get();
        CoutGuard guard;
        std::cout << std::this_thread::get_id() << " allocated "
            << (void*)dsp << "\n";
    } else {
        CoutGuard guard;
        std::cout << std::this_thread::get_id() << " re-use\n";
    }
    dsp->fn();
    std::this_thread::yield();
}

void thread_fn() {
    testFn();
    testFn();
    testFn();
}

int main() {
    std::thread t1(thread_fn);
    std::thread t2(thread_fn);
    t2.join();
    t1.join();
}
```

Live demo: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3dec7efcb0018549

```
g++ -std=c++14 -O2 -Wall -pedantic -pthread main.cpp && ./a.out
140551597459200 allocated 0x7fd4a80008e0
140551597459200 running doSomething 0x7fd4a80008e0
140551605851904 allocated 0x7fd4b00008e0
140551605851904 running doSomething 0x7fd4b00008e0
140551605851904 re-use
140551605851904 running doSomething 0x7fd4b00008e0
140551597459200 re-use
140551605851904 re-use
140551597459200 running doSomething 0x7fd4a80008e0
140551605851904 running doSomething 0x7fd4b00008e0
140551597459200 re-use
140551597459200 running doSomething 0x7fd4a80008e0
```

It's a little hard to spot but thread '9200 allocated ..4a80.. whereas thread '1904 allocated ..4b00..

Comment: This is a great answer if C++11 is available because of the thread_local support.  If C++11 is not available, a good approach is for the thread creator to provide all necessary thread context to it via thread argument (pointer to object that contains the context).

Comment: Most compilers have had some variant of thread-local storage for well over a decade. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread-local_storage#C_and_C.2B.2B https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9w1sdazb(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: That is true, but TLS is much less trivial without C++11, especially if you are writing cross-platform code.  That is why I recommend passing the context object, since it is an easier approach by comparison to TLS, and every thread library supports the concept of passing a void * to a new thread.

Answer (score 2):

No, not a good idea.

`std::map`'s methods themselves are not thread safe.

In order to really make it a "good idea", you must also make all access to your `std::map` thread-safe, by using a mutex, or an equivalent.

This includes not just the parts you have commented out, but also all other methods you're using, like `find`().

Everything that touches your `std::map` must be mutex-protected.